# Insert text in Javascript contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, text-cursor

Is there any way to insert a text (string, may or may not have html tags) to a `div`?

It has to be a `div` and not a `textarea`.

First of all, I need to get the cursor position, then insert the text in that position. It's similar to function `insertAdjacentText`, but it can only insert before or after a tag, and only works in IE.

Refer to this URL: http://yart.com.au/test/iframe.aspx. Note how you can position the cursor in the div, we need to add text at the cursor location.

Answer (score 11):

If all you need to do is insert HTML at the current selection / insertion point, that is doable.  Off the top of my head (to get you started):

- In IE, use `document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(theNewHTML)`.
- In other browsers, you should be able to use `document.execCommand("InsertHTML", ...)`.

I've used these kinds of techniques only in editable iframes/documents, not divs, but these calls should work if the div is focused, I believe.

As another answer warned, it gets ugly if you want finer-grained control, like inserting text in other places.

Answer (score 7):

**The Range and Selection Objects**

Use the [**selection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) and **[range objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Range)**.  These contain all kinds of information about the current selection, and where it lies within the node tree.

**Fair Warning:**
It's not entirely impossible to do what you're describing, but if you get very fancy, you'll be in pretty deep water of **browser quirks and incompatibilities**.  You're going to have to do a lot of **object detection**, checking to make sure you've got consistent values and methods. Incrementally check all of your browsers as you develop.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cross-browser example, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691294/96100) to work with iframes.

```
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html, selectPastedContent, iframe) {
    var sel, range;
    var win = iframe ? iframe.contentWindow : window;
    var doc = win.document;
    if (win.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
            // only relatively recently standardized and is not supported in
            // some browsers (IE9, for one)
            var el = doc.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = doc.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            var firstNode = frag.firstChild;
            range.insertNode(frag);

            // Preserve the selection
            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                if (selectPastedContent) {
                    range.setStartBefore(firstNode);
                } else {
                    range.collapse(true);
                }
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        var originalRange = sel.createRange();
        originalRange.collapse(true);
        sel.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
        if (selectPastedContent) {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.setEndPoint("StartToStart", originalRange);
            range.select();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a round-about method using insertImage.  You insert a fake image (or a small one) using the execCommand "insertImage", then you use Javascript to replace the innerHTML to add the text.

For example:

```
iFrame.focus()
iFrame.document.execCommand("insertImage", "", "fakeimage.jpg")
iFrame.document.body.innerHTML=iFrame.document.body.innerHTML.replace("<img src=\"fakeimage.jpg\">", "MY CUSTOM <b>HTML</b> HERE!")
```

Whereas iFrame is equal to the id of the intended iFrame.  Or, you could use a DIV layer by using document.getElementById("IDofDIVlayer").innerHTML

Be sure to focus before calling the execCommand, otherwise it may not work in IE.

This method works in IE too.  Tested.