# is there any way to copy to the clip bord without the flash

Tags: javascript

is there any way to copy to the clip bord without the flash and without clipboardData too because it works on ie only

i have html input tage
and have some text
i want copy it

Comment: We need more information.  For starters, what clipboard are you talking about?  The system clipboard?  A clipboard widget in a web app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clipboard access using Javascript - sans Flash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701543/clipboard-access-using-javascript-sans-flash)

Answer (score 1):

No.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701543/clipboard-access-using-javascript-sans-flash/1701718#1701718), among others.  More and more browsers are turning off clipboard access because it is a security hole.

In fact, as of version 10, flash won't allow this (mostly).

I have heard that you can enable clipboard access, **on your FF browser only**, by disabling some security settings.  Reference: http://www.febooti.com/support/website-help/website-javascript-copy-clipboard.html