# How can I convert this coffeescript to js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

```
text = child.html()
text = text.replace /(#include(\s*&lt;.*&gt;)?)/gi, '<span>$1</span>'
text = text.replace /(main\(.*\))/gi, '<span>$1</span>'
child.html text
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dcro/XKHC8/

This is an answer from my question: [Wrapping strings with a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537764/finding-keywords-using-regex-and-wrapping-them-with-a-span) I dont know how to use coffeescript and the one who answer looks unavailable.

Comment: http://js2coffee.org is a translation site

Comment: all you need to do is add paranthesis to function calls (html, and replace)

Comment: syntax error missing operand..

Comment: @BarbaraLaird That site does the opposite to what is needed here...

Comment: @OlehPrypin it does both ways, to and from coffee/java script

Comment: @Oleh - there are 2 tabs, you can go either way

Comment: here is the fiddle...all i did was add parenthesis, (semi colon is recommended though) http://jsfiddle.net/pTZQ5/

Answer (score 1):

From [js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org)

```
var text;

text = text.replace(/(#include(\s*&lt;.*&gt;)?)/gi, '<span>$1</span>');

text = text.replace(/(main\(.*\))/gi, '<span>$1</span>');

child.html(text);
```