# How to control the text copied to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in HTML and I have seen people copy/pasting parts of that table. When I tried it the result was a mess and required a lot of cleaning up, because the table contains a lot of columns with images and stuff.

Is there a way to limit the selection to the first 2 columns of the table?

OR

Is there a way to replace the text being copied (User selects "apple" and presses copy, but "banana" ends up in clipboard)?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer from a Trello developer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17528590/54378) provides a nifty solution to something similar to what you want to do. Basically, when the user presses <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you can select something useful that will then be copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no control over the clipboard whatsoever, which is one common use for Flash.

You can use `user-select: none` on the latter table `<td>` elements to block text highlighting in CSS. Since `user-select` is a new property, you must vendor prefix it for some browsers:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
```

Please see http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/ for additional info on that. It should also be noted that `user-select` is not available in IE9 or lower.

Comment: I tried this, but user-select: none; seems to be ignored by browsers.

Comment: Now that you have added the -moz- prefix, it works in Firefox. In other browsers this does not have the intended effect.

Comment: `-webkit-` will work in Chrome/Safari and `-ms-` works in IE10+. What browser(s) are you having trouble with?

Comment: In webkit and IE it makes the marked region unselectable. BUT if i select the surroundings the content in between is still copied, even when marked with user-select. Firefox behaves differently.

Comment: What are you applying `user-select` to?

Comment: `td.re` and `td.re *` which is every td except for the first 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

To limit column selection i would use user-select as Mooseman suggested. Problem is that browsers currently support their own versions of the property and not the actual user-select.

```
<style>
    .notSelectable{  
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
</style>
```

You can check it's support in http://caniuse.com/user-select-none