# Magento adminhtml grid with javascript action column

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I'm designing a custom adminhtml grid based on a model of my own, I've added an actions column to the grid which I'd like to be able to click to copy some text to the clipboard.

So in the _prepareColumns() function in Grid.php, I've added the actions column as seen below:

```
$this->addColumn('action',array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('To Clipboard'),
            'width'     => '5%',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'     => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Copy'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/*/toclipboard'),
                        'field'   => 'id'
                    )
                ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'is_system' => true,
        )
    );
```

I'd likely need to use Javascript to do this, but I'm not quite sure how to. Using the method above strangely enough also causes a page reload, even though I have successfully added `$this->setUseAjax(true);` to `__construct();`.

Would appreciate some input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Franklin P Strube: ty, pointed me in the right direction.

Final solution I used was as follows

```
 ....
          'actions'    => array(
                    array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Copy'),
                    'onclick' => "javaScriptCopyMethod();"
                )
           ),
....
```

It is considered bad practice to access a user's clipboard and most browsers prevent this nowadays, I did however find an extremely creative post linked below explaining how Trello "appears" to access the users' clipboard, the solution was actually posted by Daniel LeCheminant who is one of the Trello developers.

Solution: [How does Trello access the user's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527870/how-does-trello-access-the-users-clipboard)
Additional: https://trello.com/daniel

Answer (score 3):

There are some interesting things you can do here. Mainly, you will want to reference the [Action renderer](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Action.php) and the [Grid Javascript](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/js/mage/adminhtml/grid.js). The code you have right now should render a single link in the actions column. However, if you provide an array of actions, this will become a `<select>` list. When a `<select>` is rendered, then the grid.js file is responsible for performing the action.

Below are some examples of what you would pass in the 'actions' array:

**Javascript Onclick w/ link**

```
...
    'actions'   => array(
        array(
            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Copy'),
            'onclick' => 'window.location = "' . Mage::getUrl('*/*/toclipboard') . '"'
        )
    ),
...
```

**Confirm before running action**

```
...
    'actions'   => array(
        array(
            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Copy'),
            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/*/toclipboard'),
            'confirm' => true
        )
    ),
...
```

**Render a `<select>` list of actions (open last action in a popup)**

```
...
    'actions'   => array(
        array(
            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Copy'),
            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/*/toclipboard'),
            'confirm' => true
        ),
        array(
            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Example'),
            'onclick' => 'window.location = "' . Mage::getUrl('*/*/toclipboard') . '"'
        ),
        array(
            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Popup'),
            'popup'   => true
            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/*/toclipboard'),
        )
    ),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add a option : `'target'=>'_blank'`
Example :

```
$this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('revocation')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => '',
                'actions'   => array(array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('revocation')->__('View'),
                    'url'     => array('base' => 'adminhtml/sales_order/view'),
                    'field'   => 'order_id',
                    'target'=>'_blank'
                )),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'order_id',
            ));
```