# How to pass javascript value to controller action?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I've tried different ways to get my selected value from my **Category.php** file to controller file (**IndexController.php**). 
For this I have 3 files
**Category.php** as renderer (is a dropdown list I added to a **Grid.php** in magento)

```
<?php

class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Edit_Form_Renderer_Category extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{   
     public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{

$category = Mage::getModel('thorleif/category')->getCollection();

$category_rows = $category->getData();
$html = '<select id="select_category" name="select_category" onchange="ChooseContact(this)">';
$sep = '';
?>
<input type="text" name="id_cat" id="id_cat" value="" />
<?php

foreach ($category_rows as $rows) {

    // put the correct key here

    if (!$rows['level']) {
        $html .= $sep . "<optgroup label='{$rows['name']}'>";
        $sep = '</optgroup>';
    } else {
        $nbsp = str_repeat('&nbsp;', ($rows['level'] - 1)* 5);
        $html .= "<option value='{$rows['id_linio_category']}' title='{$rows['name']}' selected>
        $nbsp {$rows['name']}</option>";
    }
}
$html .= '</select>';
return $html;
}
}
?>
```

**Grid.php**

```
 public function _prepareColumns()
        {
    $this->addColumn('lin',
                array(
                    'header' => 'Lin Category',
                    'align' => 'left',
                    'index' => 'lin',
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'renderer' => 'Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Edit_Form_Renderer_Category'
                )
            );
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '100',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'    => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Sync'),
                            'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/sync'),
                            'field'     => 'id',
                            'target'=>'_blank'
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
            return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

**IndexController.php** where I want to get/use the Selected "Javascript_value" below from **Category.php**

```
public function syncAction()
    {

    //var_dump($_REQUEST['id_cat']);
    //var_dump($_POST['id_cat']);
    //var_dump($_GET['id_cat']);
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->load($id)
                    ->getProductCollection()->getData();

        $send = "<Request>\n";

        Foreach($products as $values){
            $code = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($values['entity_id'])->getData();
            $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($values['entity_id']);


            $send .= "<Product>".$this->getProductXml($code, $commercial, ***JAVASCRIPT_VALUE***, $stock)."</Product>\n";

        }
        $send .="</Request>"; 
        $api = new Ns_Thorleif_Adminhtml_IndexController();
        $response = $api->postProductAction($send);
        echo "<xmp>$send</xmp>";
        echo "<xmp>$response</xmp>";
    }
```

The 3 files have the result on the same front page Category.php=select dropdownlist,  Grid.php= full grid in the front including column with dropdown list, IndexController.php = Function I use to process some data.

Any suggestion please? the Idea I've tried the get/post/request, tried to save data in database and try to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You are just redirecting the control not posting any form. thats why you are not able to get the data. You can do two of the things.

1. In "ChooseContact" js function, rediect to syncAction with the selected value in get method and remove the action button.
2. In the action button, instead of redirecting the control you can call a js function and get the dropdown selected value and then redirect. Please refer : [Magento adminhtml grid with javascript action column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381217/magento-adminhtml-grid-with-javascript-action-column)

Hope this will help!

Comment: When I try to redirect using `window.location` the page goes in loop charging the content without stop. I don't know if with ajax posting data without submiting form could work?

Comment: Can you please provide me more details about the module that you building and if you can share that code, i will try to help in that. besides that please use the "ChooseContact" function to fullfill your need. You just need to redirect to your controller function with the selected value. Use the inbuild magento function to generate the admin url. You cann't directly use the admin url that will take you to dashboard only. need to have formkey with that.

Comment: I can share this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182228/my-javascript-doesnt-run-in-a-custom-magento1-9-module/182247?noredirect=1#comment255014_182247) where I explain same thing, there's more detail.

Comment: I think I have to find a form to send this Param with the grid action, in the way to use two Params getId and getLinioId something [like] (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98394/grid-action-column-getter-not-getting-my-field) but it will be a challenge get also the selected value before to send it. Sometimes I've seen that they use 'onclick' into the action I've tried with onchange but without result. The unic way when I get (but only the default selected Id) is when the webpage is refreshed like two times.