# ZeroClipboard autocopy?

Tags: jquery, flash, zeroclipboard

ZeroClipboard is the easiest and best way to copy text to the clipboard, It uses an invisible Adobe Flash movie and a JavaScript interface.

I tried it and it worked here, the code is here, and if you want to test it, click [here](http://www.tedxtube.com/6/clipboard/test.php):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/zeroclipboard-demo/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function()
   {

                   var clientTarget = new ZeroClipboard( $("#target-to-copy"), {
                 moviePath: "http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/zeroclipboard-demo/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf",
                 debug: false
               } );

               clientTarget.on( "load", function(clientTarget)
               {
                   $('#flash-loaded').fadeIn();

                   clientTarget.on( "complete", function(clientTarget, args) {
                       clientTarget.setText( args.text );
                       $('#target-to-copy-text').fadeIn();
                   } );
               } );

       });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="flash-loaded" style="display:none">Flash player is loaded.</p>
   <h2>Set Copy Target</h2>
   <p>
      <button id="target-to-copy" data-clipboard-target="clipboard-text">Click To Copy</button><br/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         // What I've done to auto-click

         $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#target-to-copy").click(); 
         });
      </script>
      <script>
         // What I've done to auto-click

         jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#target-to-copy').click();
         });
      </script>
      <textarea name="clipboard-text"  id="clipboard-text" >COPY ME PLEASE!!!!!
        </textarea>
   </p>
   <p id="target-to-copy-text" style="display:none;">Text Copied.</p>
   <h2>Paste Test</h2>
   <textarea name="paste-test" id="paste-test"  placeholder="Paste Text Here"></textarea>
```

My problem is that I want to automatically copy to clipboard without any user click. I do not plan to do something evil (I'm building a chatbot, I want him to copy text to clipboard on user's request. This is what I've tried, clicking the button with the id target-to-copy on load, using jquery; but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             // What I've done to auto-click
             $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#target-to-copy").click(); 
             });
</script>
<script>
             // What I've done to auto-click

             jQuery(function(){
                jQuery('#target-to-copy').click();
             });
</script>
```

My best guess, that the adobe flash requires that the users actually clicks on a button. What would be the solution for me (to auto-copy) on load? As I told before, I'm creating a smart chat-bot, and the user would chat with the bot and request to copy anything to clipboard, then the bot would respond with a jquery command to copy to clipboard, I don't want any user clicking anything.

Comment: "copy text to clipboard on user's request." How will the user indicate such a request?

Comment: The user will order the bot to copy text to clipboard, by writing text on the textarea and clicking on the button "Ask" of the bot.

Comment: But the user also might be chatting with the bot, so I might not always know he wants to copy to clipboard.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the ZeroClipboard documentation,](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard#limitations) this is not possible:

> ## Limitations
>
> ### User Interaction Required
>
> Due to browser and Flash security restrictions, this clipboard injection can ***ONLY*** occur when the user clicks on the invisible Flash movie. A simulated `click` event from JavaScript will not suffice as this would enable [clipboard poisoning](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9117268/Adobe_patches_Flash_clickjacking_and_clipboard_poisoning_bugs).

[There are other ways to programmatically set the clipboard text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17527870/139010) but they too require user interaction of some sort – for example, Ctrl-C (or Command-C).

Comment: But Ctrl-C or cmd-C makes my bot look dumb instead of smart.

Comment: ...sorry? There are limitations of reality you're going to have to deal with. It's irrelevant that _you_ don't intend to do something evil.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Then, the only way would linking the button "Ask" of the bot to the flash.