# Is there a way to copy a hyperlink object to the clipboard with just a button push in browser, to paste in email?

Tags: html, angularjs

Is there a way to copy a hyperlink object to the clipboard with just a button push in browser, to paste in email?

This is not a duplicate question from this post

[How does Trello access the user's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527870/how-does-trello-access-the-users-clipboard?answertab=active#tab-top)

But rather an extension of it.  The post above only describes how to copy a text string.  I'm asking how to copy a hyperlink object (with the click of a button) that i can past into an email.

Comment: you can create the link in the controller and save in `$scope.link` for example. then you can display it in the view and create a button who past this variable in the email input ( the input use `ng-model=varX` so in the controller you can change the input value doin `$scope.varX = YYYY ` )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest maybe using [Clipboard.JS](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js) in order to implement this functionality.  It works without using Flash and it works.