# Trying to programmically paste

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, paste, execcommand

I am having trouble with execCommand('paste');

My code:

```
  var copy = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  copy.innerText = "Copy";
  Sections.contextmenu.appendChild(copy);
  copy.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  });

  var paste = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  Sections.contextmenu.appendChild(paste);
  paste.innerText = "Paste";
  paste.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log("Paste");
    if (document.execCommand("paste")) {
      console.log("pasted");
    }
  });
```

Copy worked right out of the box. I cannot get paste to work. I see "Paste" in the console, but nothing is pasted. I've read some things that say that this functionality needs to be explicitly turned on in Firefox. Is there no way (other than using flash... This is talked about in the research I've done) to execute "paste" in a content-editable element programmatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969403/why-is-document-execcommandpaste-not-working-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paste` command is disabled in web content (it’s only available in a browser extension). It’s disabled presumably because it would allow any website to steal the clipboard’s content. From the [MDN documentation on `execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand#Commands):

> #### `paste`
>
> Pastes the clipboard contents at the insertion point (replaces current selection). Disabled for web content.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
console.log(document.exeCommand('paste')
```

If false maybe you need a permission to use it or your navigator can't support it
You can also use the Clipboard API, which would obliterate the exeCommand

Comment: I believe Clipboard API has been shutdown for security reasons in just about every browser other than IE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060109/why-is-writing-to-the-clipboard-in-js-considered-a-security-hole