# HTML id with javascript to trigger a write to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

When I run this script (embedded in a HTML page) 'GG' isn't copied to the clipboard. Can someone help/explain why and assist me in getting it working? Thanks.

```
document.getElementById("blah3");
let s ="GG";
navigator.clipboard.writeText(s);
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: what does `document.getElementById("blah3");` have to do with anything? It simply does nothing at all useful - read [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API#security_considerations) to see the varied reasons your code may not work

Comment: ^^ specifically understand what [transient activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation#transient_activation) means

Comment: Focus on my "document.getElementById("blah3");" isn't relevant, but seeing as you mentioned it, I have an element elsewhere that is ascribed with id="blah2" which is used to get to the script.
I'm not after user event/action based triggering of the clipboard, I just want to simply write GG to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Like the link in the comments says, you need to attach a clipboard write to a user action for security reasons. Usually you make a user click a button and add an event listener for it.

```js
function writeToClipboard() {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText('GG');
}

document.querySelector('#my-button').addEventListener('click', writeToClipboard)
```

DISCLAIMER: THE FOLLOWING IS FOR EDUCATIONAL PURPOSES. PLEASE DO NOT TRY TO DODGE SECURITY FEATURES.

If you really want to shimmy around security you can do some questionable things.

You could keep trying to write until the user does something and it succeeds. Using a timeout will prevent the thread from blocking. Best to wait a few ms before polling again so as not to make the CPU go brrr

```js
function tryToWrite() {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText('GG').catch(() => setTimeout(tryToWrite, 50));
}

tryToWrite();
```

or you could attach it to events that are likely to happen

```js
let wrote = false;

function writeToClipboard() {
  if (wrote) return;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText('GG').then(() => wrote = true);
}

window.addEventListener('focus', writeToClipboard, {once: true});
window.addEventListener('mousedown', writeToClipboard, {once: true});
window.addEventListener('keydown', writeToClipboard, {once: true});
```

You'll always be restricted to the user interacting with the page in some way before you can write.

Comment: BTW: Thank you Jaromanda X for your time and effort
and thank you too Chris, but why is writing a fixed string to the clipboard a security issue?

Comment: @Micklos The answer to that can be read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060109/why-is-writing-to-the-clipboard-in-js-considered-a-security-hole

Comment: @ Joseph. OK. even if only 1% of people were silly enough to paste without the slightest glance of what they pasted - whereupon one would likely instantly know if it looks like the 'expected' link or not, then I suppose that's 1% too many, so fair enough on that one. But I'd say far more people can be and probably are scammed by far more seductive event triggered clipboard writes.  I found the statement 'some ppl may not want their clipboard' written to' quite powerful.
But for personal use I can see a lot of good uses for it, so can it be done?

Comment: @Micklos if it's just for personal use, write a desktop app instead of a web app. You'll have full control of your system.

Comment: @Chris. That's what I was trying to do but the clipboard method I used at the top didn't work. Could you enlighten me as to how it could be done e.g, on page load a page contained string variable gets copied to the clipboard, given that the above failed for me?