# Replace paragraph by <br /> tag in div with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to put `<br />` only in div contenteditable while user is pressing ENTER key? I must manage the content of that div in XML after send, but some browsers translate new lines as `<p>`, some (in example Google Chrome) as `<div>`.

The good solution will be force to make new lines the same in all browsers (only `<p>` or only `<div>`) too.

PS: I'm using jQuery and PHP.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220939/force-ie-contenteditable-element-to-create-line-breaks-on-enter-key-without-brea

Comment: For firefox take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla. Look for the argument "insertBrOnReturn". Not sure for IE though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trapping the user keyboard event of pressing the Enter key?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but note that <shift><enter> generally inserts a <br />, I belive.

I wonder if you could force a shift in onKeypress?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible at all. I've tried to rewrite event keyCode, but it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<div contenteditable="true">test1<div></div></div>`

You can force single-spacing when you hit return in a content-editable element by seeding it with an inner DIV like so: