# Stop <p> tag generation on carriage return in a contenteditable <div>

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a `div` tag with the `contenteditable` attribute, I want to stop `p` tags from being inserted when the user does a carriage return. Is it possible? The is an ASP.NET app and the `div` is rendered from a `asp:panel`.

Comment: First of all learn basics on how web works. You should distinguish between a client and server side. This definitely has nothing to do with the server-side technologies like ASP.NET or C#. What would be a difference between `div` generated by C#, PHP, Python or for example Ruby?

Comment: Well I am desperate for a solution and was hoping that if there were no client side solution a server side "workaround" could be suggested. In my opinion it never hurts to give as much information as possible. You can't say they have nothing to do with each other when there is a line of communication between the client and server.

Comment: Well, therefore I was advising you to learn basics of how web works. If you would do that, you know that it's nonsense. Forget that your page is generated by anything. Save it as plain HTML and play with that HTML (plus client-side technologies like JavaScript).

Comment: Well I woudn't call it pain old "nonsense" but fair enough, touche

Comment: What browser are you using to get the `<p>` on carriage return? Firefox gives me the nonsensical `<br></br>`, chrome gives `<div><br></div>` for some stupid reason and IE Edge likes to nest `div`s infinitely.

Comment: I have also tried chrome with the jsfiddle example provided by Mohit Shrivastava below, and the results are the same as I experienced before.

Comment: Lots of sarcasm with no answers is the way of the self righteous.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy: Have to agree with Dawn -- including that information is useful. ASP.Net is much more than just a server-side rendering engine like PHP. It has a client-side aspect as well. Also, context is useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. For that reason I'm advising him to forget about ASP.NET, isolate just plain HTML (plus CSS and JavaScript) and play with that. He needs to localize what's causing his problem. More technologies will be affecting the result, harder it will be to localize the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force IE contentEditable element to create line breaks on Enter key, without breaking Undo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220939/force-ie-contenteditable-element-to-create-line-breaks-on-enter-key-without-bre)