# In IE, entering a newline causes a <p><br><p> to be inserted for contentEditable

Tags: jquery, html

For some reason IE wraps each newline with a `<p>` tag and it's causing some issues with the multi line banner I have.

I know Chrome wraps it in div and Firefox has a br tag, and I'm trying to strip the p tags to replace it with a `<br>` after a newline. Every time I enter a newline IE puts in a `<p></br></p>` and I've tried many different ways using jQuery selectors and splitting the HTML and joining it but nothing has worked so far.

How can I fix this to make it mimic either Chrome or Firefox's behavior? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force IE contentEditable element to create line breaks on Enter key, without breaking Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220939/force-ie-contenteditable-element-to-create-line-breaks-on-enter-key-without-bre)

Comment: Please post your code and a simplified example to show us the issue