# how to add div tags to content on enter key instead of p tags

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

On enter key press in a `contenteditable` iframe,  `<P>` tags are appended. I want to stop appending that `<P>` tags and append `<div>` tags instead.

Any suggestions will be valuable

Comment: Near enough a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057881/avoid-ie-contenteditable-element-to-create-paragraphs-on-enter-key

Comment: @Anand: This question is about a general "problem" with `contenteditable`. No code required here. It would just be: `<div contenteditable="true">Something</div>`.

Comment: @Jeff: this is not the duplicate of that link which u mentioned. there the case is br and here it is div

Comment: I didn't say it was an exact duplicate, just a "near enough" ... and the winning answer still applies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some Keyup event and replace it

```
$('.myEditable').keyup(function(){
   var sanitazed = $(this).text().replace(/<p[^<]*?>/g, '<div>').replace(/<\/p[^<]*?>/g, '</div>');
   $(this).text(sanitazed);
});
```

Comment: While this would probably work, it would also cause problems if you have paragraphs in your content that you want to keep.

Comment: Because replacing is data destructive, and something like this could be difficult to track down if you have paragraphs in your data and want to keep the existing ones there.  As I said, it'd work, but I'm not sure I like it as a solution, hence, -1.  Sorry :)