# How to add class or id or CSS style in execCommand formatBlock 'p' tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, execcommand

I want to use execcommand 'formatblock' for select a line by 'p' tag or span with specific class or Id or any css style in my contenteditable div(own rich text editor). i searched a lot for this, but i could not find anything which valuable for me.

```
document.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'p');
```

**How can i add class or id or css in this code?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to add id or class for CSS in content editable div, then you will use below code---

```
          <script>
             function CssFnctn()
                {
                  document.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'p')
                  var listId = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
                  $(listId).addClass("oder2");
                 }
           </script>


.oder2
    {
       padding-left: 3em;
    }
```

Comment: Not very reliable. Often you can get adjacent nodes of a text selection instead of the new `p`.

Comment: @Tim yes getting that problem. Any alternative solution?

Comment: @Ankur Aggarwal: I couldn't come up with one. In the end I gave up on contenteditable, instead am using Markdown. Might go back to contenteditable with Web Standards improve.

Comment: It should be `window.getSelection().focusNode` without a `parentNode`

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to do it. Just use execCommand 'insertHTML' instead to replace selected text with wrapped code. Like this:

```
selection = window.getSelection().toString();
wrappedselection = '<span class="accent" style="somestyle">' + selection + '</span>';
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, wrappedselection);
```

This will remove breaklines, tags like `<b>`, `<i>` and other intext-html-formatting - to keep them you need smth like this (thx to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5643742/8640520)):

```
selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();
span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(selection);
wrappedselection = '<span class="accent1">'+span.innerHTML+'</span>';
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, wrappedselection);
```

This insertHTML does not works with IE. Check Documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution.

**Javascript:**

```
function line(){

              window.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'p');
                selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
                selectedElement.style.marginBottom = '100px';
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="addMarginBottom" onclick="javascript:line();"/>
<div class="textcontent" contenteditable ="true"></div>
```

This is work perfectly for me. But i can not make jsfiddle right now. This is work for one line fine but not multiple line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/57/

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').click(function () {
     var sel = window.getSelection();
     var range = document.createRange();
     el = document.getElementById('one'); //Get the element
     range.selectNodeContents(el);
     sel.removeAllRanges();
     sel.addRange(range);
     document.execCommand('formatblock', false, null); //execute command.
     document.execCommand('bold', false, null); //execute command.
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p id="one">Sample text</p>
  <p>Sample text 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually when i put my cursor in a line of the div then i click a button which belongs with execcommand formatblock 'P'. Then the line text will be go in the p tag. My question is--- is it possible to add any class or id or css with this p tag?

Comment: So when you add a line text in the p tag then the focus will be set on the p tag, right? If yes, then you can select the focused element by following ways and then add class/style on it: 

// Get the focused element:
var $focused = $(':focus');

// No jQuery:
var focused = document.activeElement;

// Does the element have focus:
var hasFocus = $('foo').is(':focus');

// No jQuery:
elem === elem.ownerDocument.activeElement;

Correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Would you please give me any example?

Comment: You should create a fiddle for your code which adds a text line in "P" tag. Then it will be easier for me to help you.

Answer (score 1):

To add the class to the p tag, I think it should actually be like this...

```
function CssFnctn() {
  document.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'p')
  var listId = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode;
  listId.classList = 'oder2';
}
```

Notice the anchorNode instead of focusNode

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ended up using jQuery.

```
document.execCommand(optionCommand, false, null);

let snippets = $('.js-editor-content-snippet');
let lists = snippets.find('ul, ol');

lists.css({ margin: '0', padding: '0 0 0 20px' });
lists.find('li').css({ margin: '0 0 12px' });
```

There is also this great library that could be helpful: https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Class-Applier-Module

```
rangy.createClassApplier(String theClass[, Object options[, Array tagNames]])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to reliably find the element(s) created by `execCommand` is to compare the list of child elements before and after running it. Any elements that didin't exist before `execCommand` was called we're added by `execCommand`.

Here's an example:

```js
// `container` is the contenteditable container element
// Get all the existing elements
const elementsBefore = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll("*"));
// Run the command (wrap selection in a p tag)
document.execCommand("formatblock", false, "p");
// Get all the existing elements again
const elementsAfter = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll("*"));
// Find any that elements didn't exist before `execCommand` and select the first one
const newElement = elementsAfter.filter(e => !elementsBefore.includes(e))[0]
// `newElements` should now be the p tag that was added
```