# Adding CSS Class with execCommand()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, execcommand

```
function iBlockquote(){
    rich_body_eng.document.execCommand('FormatBlock', false, "<blockquote>");
    var quote = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
    $(quote).addClass("quote");
}
```

Above I'm adding a blockquote to the selected text with `execCommand()`. Another thing I want to do is add a `CSS` class called `quote` to the `<blockquote` tag, so the output would be something like `<blockquote class="quote">Some text</blockquote>`. It doesn't seem to work. Please help.

I'm using this question as a guide. [How to add class or id or CSS style in execCommand formatBlock 'p' tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380628/how-to-add-class-or-id-or-css-style-in-execcommand-formatblock-p-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot reproduce in Firefox, here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ns1pyko8/2/), I've tried adding the class with jQuery and with plain JavaScript, both work.

### HTML

```
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```

### CSS

> This is just to visualize the `blockquote`.

```
.quote{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:khaki;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
document.designMode = "on";
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, "<blockquote>");
var quote = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
$(quote).addClass("quote");
//quote.className = "quote";
```

Maybe this helps, maybe I did something differently :)

Comment: While this does add a class to the element, it does not add the class to the HTML that contenteditable creates.

Answer (score 0):

you're adding the class to the wrong element. Try

```
var newEl = this.options.ownerDocument.getSelection().focusNode;
newEl.className = newEl.className + " new-para";
```