# How to set an "id" to a tag using the execCommand in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, execcommand

I am trying to make up a basic text editor, and I used execCommand a lot for this.
However, I want to create a heading in such a way, so that whenever user will click on the heading button(in text editor), the execCommand will make up a **new heading** and should add **id** to the newly created heading, so that, later I can create interlinks in document with just a single click.

Let say my input in for heading text editor is:

Create a heading with id

I've tried this to create a heading with id:

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, header).id = userSelection;
```

HTML output for this:

```
<h3><a href="#Create a heading with id">Create a heading with id</a></h3>
```

As you can see, the id is not added to the HTML output, so how can I add an id to it?
I've also tried this link but didn't get much:
[How to add class or id or CSS style in execCommand formatBlock 'p' tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380628/how-to-add-class-or-id-or-css-style-in-execcommand-formatblock-p-tag)

Please help :)

**EDIT :**

Well, I got a hack to do this:
We can add the id to the newly created tag by using the Query selector so that whenever I will create a new tag using execCommand, I will find that tag by selecting the main div(in which editing is going on), and after finding that header tag, I can simply add the id to it.
Like I used this to create a header tag in div(contenteditable="true"):

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, header);
```

And to add 'id' to this newly created tag, use this:

```
let elemMain = $("#editor " + header);   
// this will find the div with id="editor" and then find the header tag inside it.

elemMain[elemMain.length - 1].id = userSelection;
//this will add an id to the last header tag inside of div.
```

Well, this is just a hack to get work done, but if anyone finds out a direct way to add 'id' to tag using execCommand then most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding  id attribute to the `<body>` tag here using execCommand.

Using javascript :

```
var idValue = "body-element";
document.execCommand(document.body.setAttribute("id", idValue));
```

Using jquery :

```
var idValue = "body-element";
document.execCommand($('body').attr('id', idValue));
```

Working snippet for newly created element:

```js
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is newly created paragraph ( inspect this element and see the id.)");
para.appendChild(node);
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
var idValue = "new_id";
document.execCommand(para.setAttribute("id", idValue));
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="div1">
<p id="p1">This is an old paragraph.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi nitin, I don't want to add id to the body tag, intead I need to add the id to the newly created tag like creating a heading tag (H1) and providing it the id, so that I can make up a Table of contents from that header ID, by creating dynamic links.

Comment: body was for example, you could add newly created element by same way

Comment: @Prashant : I've updated the answer with create element example, inspect newly created paragraph and see the the id "new_id"

Comment: Actually Nitin, I don't want to add a tag to div in this way, my situation is "I am creating a basic text editor", so whenever a user will enter the text, that text will be converted to a heading tag on click of a button (where I actually change the **entered text** to a **heading** using execCommand) and I was unable to set the **ID** for that tag. Now, what you provided is actually a good way, I can use it, but too much work to do, as first I have to get the **selected text from user** then make a tag for it and then add ID to it and then replace that entered text with the created tag

Comment: Well Nitin, Thanks much for your answer, and I get a small hack to do, which I edited in my question, check out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same requirement to use `document.execCommand` to manipulate a `contenteditable` element, and eventually resorted to the `innerHTML` option of `execCommand`.  For example...

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<div id='myId'>Hello World!</div>")
```

...adds the specified HTML at the insertion point, leaving the HTML element addressable by `myId`.  The drawback to this technique is that one has to construct the HTML string.  An alternative is to employ the `createElement` function, and then reference the `outerHTML` of the element node when calling `execCommand`...

```
let elemNode = document.createElement('div')
elemNode.id = 'myId'
elemNode.innerText = 'Hello World!'
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, elemNode.outerHTML)
```

Note that I only tested this on Chrome.

Hope this helps anyone else finding this nook of the internet.