# How to add a css class on any html tag using execCommand while developing wysiwyg editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text-editor

I am searching from a time but i am not getting solution ,also didn't get any proper solution on stackoverflow.

I want to make **WYSIWYG EDITOR** for my particular need . I want to select particular content area and want to add class. My all others function are working .

[Editor Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWvDH.png)

I have visited all [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380628/how-to-add-class-or-id-or-css-style-in-execcommand-formatblock-p-tag) please help me . 
I tried to add **blockquote** tag first then i tried to add CSS class using jquery.
Here is the code:

```
function addclass()
     {
        editor.document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, "<blockquote>");
        $('blockquote').addClass("redcolor");

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost done try following:

```
function add_custom_class()
     {
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, "blockquote");
        $('blockquote').addClass("redcolor");
        }
```

Comment: editor is the iframe name , this is not the problem to skip the keyword editor .

Comment: @SaddamAzad feel free to add it later, just try what I wrote, please.

Comment: Honestly not working. I try your code . By your code even the blockquote is not applying.