# Javascript dom - Insert node to a specific div at cursor position avoiding other divs

Tags: javascript

The code below works, it inserts to cursor position, but I need to be sure the node is added only to div `mydiv` and not to other part of the page. For example the other div `another`. With this code if I click on other positions different from `mydiv` the span is added there.
Can you suggest me a clean approach to solve this?

Can I use something like

```
if(window.getSelection().parentNode.id != "mydiv") return; 
if (window.getSelection().rangeCount == 0) var a = document.createRange(); else var a = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
<div id="another"></div>
<a href="" onclick="addShort('Hello','Bye')" >Test</a>
```

```js
function addShort(id,name,custom=null){ 

  var a = _range;
  var b = _selectedText;    
  var z = document.createElement("span");
    
  b = " <span data-id='"+id+"' data-type=\""+custom+"\"><span 
  contenteditable=\"true\" > "+name+" </span></span>&nbsp;";

  z.innerHTML=b;
  a.deleteContents();
  a.insertNode(z);
    
}

if (window.getSelection().rangeCount == 0)
    var a = document.createRange();
else    
    var a = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    
_range = a;
_selectedText = a.toString();   
e.preventDefault;   
    
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339857/how-to-know-if-selected-text-is-inside-a-specific-div Maybe this helps you.

Comment: if (window.getSelection().rangeCount == 0)
 var a = document.createRange();
else 
 var a = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
 
_range = a;
_selectedText = a.toString(); 
e.preventDefault; 
 
});

Comment: your edited function has syntax issues and doesnt seem complete....

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) has properties `anchorNode` (“Returns the Node in which the selection begins.”) and `focusNode` (“Returns the Node in which the selection ends.”) - so I’d try to use those to figure out, whether your current selection is inside of your target element, or not. That probably doesn’t cover the case that the selection starts before and/or ends after your target node. Suppose in that case, you can only alert the user to that fact, and reject the operation?

Comment: gets the last selection made on the page and us it to insert the span, is there a way to get "a" only if selection is made within a div with give class name?

Comment: Something like if(window.getSelection().parentNode.id != "mydiv") return;
 
if (window.getSelection().rangeCount == 0)
 var a = document.createRange();
else 
 var a = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);