# Can a `range.insertNode` be undone using browser's undo, in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, undo, rich-text-editor

I am working on a `contenteditable` div to make a simple RichText-Editor. One of the requirement I have is to be able insert html chunk at cursor postion on a button event.

I was able to get that part working fine by using `range`, `selection`, `range.insertNode(nodeHTML)` or `range.pasteHTML(nodeHTML)` based on browser. But I couldn't get two things, which ideally I would like to have

1. To be Able to undo the inserted node, using browser's undo. Somehow, browser ignores above actions.
2. To move the cursor at the end of inserted node. So that user can start writing after

I know I can use something out of many editors available, which does this very well, but If I get this I would not have to. Any help or even suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: This might help you: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/ - Also, take a look at the demos.

Comment: Unfortunately Rangy has no undo functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Answer rewritten August 2013**

Unfortunately not, although things are improving. Programmatic DOM mutations other than those triggered by `document.execCommand()` do not go on the browser's built-in undo stack. However, there have been two recent developments:

- IE 11 has new [`ms-beginUndoUnit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#BeginUndoUnit) and [`ms-endUndoUnit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#EndUndoUnit) commands
- There is a [spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/undomanager/raw-file/tip/undomanager.html) in the works for an undo stack available to web developers, parts of  which have been implemented in WebKit and Firefox (note: [it's disabled by default in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888611/undomanager-support-in-firefox) and apparently also in WebKit).

Until the situation improves, you could use `document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, "<b>Some html</b>");` but this is not supported in IE.

Comment: I guess IE users have to do without undo then. Using, `insertHTML` is the solution to both of my issues. Thanks. And btw, your rangy is impressive.

Comment: It looks like Microsoft may be the first to do something about this issue; IE 11 has the commands *ms-beginUndoUnit* and *ms-endUndoUnit* which collect any DOM changes that occur between using the two, pushing them to the undo stack as a single undo step.

Comment: @AndyE: Oo, I didn't know about that. Good news, although I'd rather they'd implemented the spec.

Comment: @AndyE: I've rewritten my answer to reflect the current situation. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @TimDown: No problem.  I'd prefer they implement the UndoManager spec too, but perhaps they are opposed to it for some reason. I don't presently have time to reboot into Windows, but I could imagine a use case where you want to transparently manipulate user input before it's painted.  With the IE implementation, you'd need to undo first (which would trigger events) so as to override the undo step created by the user input.  I wasn't aware that Firefox had an implementation of UndoManager, though.  That's pretty cool.

Comment: @AndyE: I've spent a few minutes trying and failing to create a working example of undoing user input using the Firefox implementation, but I think the failure is  likely to be my fault for not reading the spec correctly.

Comment: @TimDown: I've bookmarked, but haven't fully read the spec yet either, so I can't help you there ;-).

Comment: Any Updates on this in 2023?

Comment: @FarooqAlaulddin: Work on the undo API appears to have stalled, so I'm afraid the answer is no.