# insertHTML with div and span tags in contenteditable section

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, html, inserthtml

In a contenteditable div, I am attempting to use insertHTML to insert a special `<div>` and/or `<span>`. For whatever reason, this appears to not be allowed as insertHTML removes the div/span before inserting the remaining content. As an example:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "<div class='btn equals'><a href='#'>=</a></div>");
```

Does anyone know a work-around or alternative method for doing what I'm trying to do? A custom tag works on WebKit but know that the concept isn't guaranteed to be supported in all browsers:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "<btn_equals><a href='#'>=</a></btn_equals>");
```

Comment: The `InsertHTML` command isn't available in IE either, in case that matters to you.

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6691294/96100

Comment: @Tim Down Thanks for the suggestions. We ended up adjusting the CSS so it didn't use a div. Still, very weird. (And yes, I do know that IE doesn't offer insertHTML. I'll deal with that when I get there. :-)

Answer (score 2):

May be this is too late but I was in similar problem and we tried same thing as yours, and solution is not to include any single or double quite ' or " in text which is to be inserted

e.g.

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', true, "<div class=btnequals>this is test</div>");
```