# Set anchor name with execCommand

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, execcommand, rangy

I know how to set an `<a />` tag with the `href` attribute in a `contenteditable` like this:

```
execCommand("CreateLink", false, "#jumpmark");
```

which will result in

```
<a href="#jumpmark">selection</a>
```

However I cannot figure out how to set an anchor `name` instead of the `href`.
This is my desired result:

```
<a name="jumpmark">selection</a>
```

Can anyone help me?

**Side notes:** I am using jQuery and Rangy as libraries, however I would prefer a solution that works directly with execCommand.

**Update:** Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fjYHr/ Select some text and click the button. All I want is that with the button click a link is inserted with a name attribute set instead of the href.

Comment: I'm guessing `execCommand` is something of "Rangy" (don't know what that is). Couldn't you just use jQuery's `.attr("name", "jumpmark")` to do that?

Comment: No the `execCommand` is a browser command which enables you to change content in `contenteditable` elements. See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html for an explanation

Comment: Can't believe I've never seen that before. Is it necessary to use `execCommand`? Why couldn't you use jQuery (or plain Javascript) to create the element, set its attribute, and then append it to the DOM where you want?

Comment: because I need to work on the current selection. Specifically I don't have a jQuery object that I can append to, meaning I don't have a DOM node that I can work on.

Comment: What do you mean the "current selection". You don't need jQuery objects or whatever, forget I said that. Just think of the normal way you add elements to the page with Javascript - use `createElement`, set its attribute, append to DOM. I guess I still don't understand why it's _necessary_ to use `execCommand`

Comment: @Horen: `I don't have a jQuery object that I can append to`: You can make one `$('closestStaticElememnt').append('<a>...</a>')` or `$('<a>...</a>').appendTo('closestStaticelEmemnt')`, see [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for additional research.

Comment: @Ian here is a jsfiddle that shows the way I intend to use it: http://jsfiddle.net/fjYHr/ Select some text and then click the button. How would you do that with jQuery only?

Comment: @Horen Ahh I finally understand. Didn't know you actually meant the text selection when you said "selection". This is a thinker...

Comment: @Ian Ok, sorry if it was unclear. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like the following, which is adapted from the `pasteHtmlAtCaret()` function from [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691294/96100):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F8Zny/

Code:

```
function surroundSelectedText(element) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            element.appendChild( document.createTextNode(range.toString()) );
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(element);

            // Preserve the selection
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.setStartAfter(element);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        var selRange = document.selection.createRange();
        element.appendChild( document.createTextNode(selRange.text) );
        selRange.pasteHTML(element.outerHTML);
    }
}
```

If you must use `document.execCommand()` then you could use the `InsertHTML` command in non-IE browsers. However, IE does not support it.

```
document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, '<a name="jumpmark">selection</a>');
```

Comment: How do you place the cursor after the anchor when it's inserted. If the anchor is placed at the end of the line it's not possible to edit outside the anchor. This is also a problem if the anchored text is the only text on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using Rangy, but I don't how to use it at all. Before I realized what Rangy was, I looked up how to get the current selection. I found a function that gets it and replaces it with a passed in value. I ended up modfiying it, but here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/fjYHr/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#setlink").click(function () {
        replaceSelectedText("jumplink");
    });
});

function replaceSelectedText(nameValue) {
    var sel, sel2, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel2 = ""+sel;  // Copy selection value
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var newA = document.createElement("a");
            newA.name = nameValue;
            newA.innerHTML = sel2;
            range.insertNode(newA);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // Not sure what to do here
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        var newA = "<a name='" + nameValue.replace(/'/g, "") + "'>" + range.text + "</a>";
        range.text = newA;
    }
}
```

Notice how I store the original current selection, then replace it with an `<a>` element that gets its `name` set with the passed-in value.

As for the `document.selection` part (which seems to be used by IE < 9), I'm not 100% sure that the code I provided will work (actually allow HTML in the selection, and not escaping it). But it's my attempt :)

Comment: Looks good - thanks :) I'll test for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, and no problem. You'd obviously want to change the name of the function and/or clean it up a little. It looks like `document.selection` (the `else if` part) is mainly used in IE < 9. Otherwise, `window.selection` looks pretty standard. If you have IE < 9 to test on, you could try just using an HTML string, so who knows

Comment: @Horen And I just updated the answer with what I would try using for the second part. Not sure if it will work, can't test either :)

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen `execCommand` is rather limited in the attributes you can set, as such you cannot set the `name` attribute using it - only the `href`.

As you have `jQuery` set as a tag, you can use that as an alternative:

```
var $a = $('<a></a>').attr('name', 'jumpmark').appendTo('body');
```

**Update**

> I need to work on the current selection. Specifically I don't have a jQuery object that I can append to, meaning I don't have a DOM node that I can work on

In this case use a plugin such as [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to get the selection which you can then amend with jQuery as required.