# How to extract styled text from div to a Selection object JavaScript and other

Tags: javascript, styles, selection, getselection

Ok, I have 2 problems, I've gotten internet explore to replace selected text with the text from a div element but I haven't managed to do it with firefox (the 'no idea' bit) and ontop of that I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the styled text to be output from the div; I mean, that was the whole point of using the div so the text could be styled. Any ideas? Btw inputText is the reference to the div element.

The main area of problem is on the 5th to last line of this:

```
            if (highlight){ 
                if (ie){
                    document.selection.createRange().text = inputText.innerHTML;
                }
                else{
                    // (no idea!?!) = inputText.innerHTML;
                }
                inputText.parentNode.removeChild(inputText);
            }
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're asking, but does this answer it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6691294/96100

Answer (score 0):

This used to work for me. Hope it helps you.

```
var r = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
r.deleteContents();
r.insertNode(inputText);
```