# HTML5 draggable elements within contenteditable div - stops working after first drop - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, contenteditable

I am trying to create a few draggable elements (tokens) that can be dragged around inside a contenteditable div. It seems that everything is working except that... after I drag one element and drop it, I cannot drag it again. It seems that I cannot bind to it's dragstart event again.

Any idea why this happens and how can i fix it?

Here's a link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gXScu/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    Testime siinkohal seda, et kuidas<br />
    on võimalik asja testida.
    <span class="draggable" draggable="true" contenteditable="false">Token</span>
</div>
<span class="draggable" draggable="true" contenteditable="false">Token 2</span>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
var bindDraggables = function() {
    console.log('binding draggables', $('.draggable').length);
    $('.draggable').off('dragstart').on('dragstart', function(e) {
        if (!e.target.id)
            e.target.id = (new Date()).getTime();
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.target.outerHTML);
        console.log('started dragging');
        $(e.target).addClass('dragged');
    }).on('click', function() {
        console.log('there was a click');
    });
}

$('#editor').on('dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('#editor').on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var e = e.originalEvent;
    var content = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    var range = null;
  if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) { // Chrome
    range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }
  else if (e.rangeParent) { // Firefox
    range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(e.rangeParent, e.rangeOffset);
  }
    console.log('range', range)
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges(); sel.addRange(range);

  $('#editor').get(0).focus(); // essential
  document.execCommand('insertHTML',false, content);
    //$('#editor').append(content);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
    bindDraggables();
    console.log($('[dragged="dragged"]').length);
    $('.dragged').remove();
});

bindDraggables();
```

CSS:

```
#editor {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
}
.draggable {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    background: yellow;
    cursor: move !important;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine on Firefox, therefore most likely it is a Chrome's bug. And it occurs only if you use `insertHTML` command. When I replaced it with `$('#editor').append(content)` everything works fine...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also tried a few hacks but none of them seems to work. I was inspecting HTML and I found that in your example the newly inserted **content** don't have any **contenteditable** attribute assigned and when I assigned to it manually then it started working fine.

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/gXScu/8/

I just added this line

`$('.draggable').attr("contenteditable", false);` in `bindDraggables` method.

I agree with Reinmar explanation over **contenteditable**.

Comment: @Reinmar: :-). So it seems that if we do 'insertHTML' via 'document.execCommand' then Chrome is removing 'contenteditable' attribute silently :-).

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome might give inconsistent results with using 'document.execCommand('insertHTML',false, content);'. To fix that, change it to 'pasteHtmlAtCaret(content)'. Function can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div/6691294#6691294

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Chrome has a bug (not a surprise - `contenteditable` is the most buggy feature in all browsers). Your code works perfectly fine on Firefox, but for some reason element inserted into editable with `insertHTML` command cannot be dragged any more.

I tried few hacks, but only one worked - inserting other element and then replacing it.

So instead:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, content);
```

Use something like this:

```
var spanId = 'temp-' + (new Date()).getTime();

// Insert span with zero-width space (so it isn't visible and it isn't empty).
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<span id="' + spanId + '">\u200b</span>');
// Replace that span with our dragged content.
$('#' + spanId).replaceWith(content);
```

You can try this here: http://jsfiddle.net/gXScu/5/. I also corrected wrong order of this:

```
$('.dragged').remove();
bindDraggables();
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer and a good explanation, thanks! I have chosen  Imran's answer though because it is a bit more straightforward and doesn't require creating an extra element.

Comment: The only thing that would be missing imho is the caret indicator to show where the item is going to be placed after mouseup. Is that somehow possible?