# How to create cross-browser draggable elements inside contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, contenteditable

I am looking to create the following:

Contenteditable div, that has simple HTML in it, for example:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is a paragraph of <b>bold</b> <span class="draggable" draggable="true" contenteditable="false">text</span></p>
    <p>This is another para<br />graph</p>
</div>
```

My goal is for the user to be able to edit the contents of the div, but not the individual `.draggable` spans. Instead, they should be able to drag and drop them to where they like - but I would also like that while dragging, the cursor/caret would snap to spaces between words - so that the user can only drop the `span` between words, not inside them.

Ideally, once the user drops the `span`, it would be placed exactly between words, ie, there should be 1 space before and after it (and the spaces from its previous position should be removed).

My main question is, **how can I snap/position the caret (blinking cursor) between the words while dragging the `span` elements**? I need this solution to work in all modern browsers and if possible, also IE8 and up.

My secondary question is **how can I ensure that there is always a space before and after the `span` after dropping it?**

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @Teemu I updated my post with clearer questions.

Comment: I'd suggest you to forget IE8, practically you'd need to create a different application for it. Eventhandling and especially text selectionhandling model in older IEs differ totally from modern browsers. What comes to the programming details, earned that rep you have, you very well know, how SO works...

Comment: Have a look on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900032/html5-draggable-elements-within-contenteditable-div-stops-working-after-first There's an example that can help you.