# JavaScript: get cursor position in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, cursor-position, getcaretpos

I am pretty new to JavaScript and hope someone here can help me with the following:

Primarily looking for a solution in IE 8 - if it can cover other browsers / versions even better. 
I have a page with only one contenteditable div that is created dynamically and contains both text and HTML tags. 
On the page I want to add a button that inserts certain text at the cursor position into this div.

So far I have the following code which works fine as long as I select a text in the div but if I just position my cursor there without selecting anything it inserts my text outside the div.

How can I get it to add my text always at the cursor position the same way it does now at the selection position ? (I don't even need it to replace a selection as it would only be required at the cursor position. Also, this would only be required for one specific div.)

My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test()
    {
        var input = "TEST";
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(input);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" contenteditable>This is a test text.</div><br />
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help with this, Tim

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that the `<button>` element steals the focus and destroys the selection by the time the `click` event has fired in IE. You could make the `<button>` unselectable, which would prevent it being able to receive focus. This is done using the [`unselectable` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE:

```
<button type="button" unselectable="on" onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/aqAYUwu/5

Another alternative which is less good in my view is to use the `mousedown` event instead and prevent the default action:

```
<button type="button" unselectable="on"
    onmousedown="test(); return false">Test</button>
```

You can find a cross-browser function to insert HTML at the current cursor position in a `contenteditable` element here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691294/96100

One final note: `contenteditable` isn't a boolean attribute so strictly speaking you should give it a value (i.e. `<div contenteditable="true">`), although `<div contenteditable>` does work in all browsers I've tried it in.

Comment: Thanks for this. The comments and links are very helpful even though it still seems to lose focus and inserts the text above my div (it still works fine when i have selected a text part before). Is there maybe a way I can force it to insert into a specific div to avoid this ?

Comment: @user2571510: Does the the JSBin link not work properly for you? It's fine in IE 7 for me.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. You are right regarding a button getting focus. My problem here is that the button in question is inside a Bootbox dialog (like a prompt box) and there the button only has a class but no id so i dont know how to add the unselectable attribute to it.

Comment: @user2571510: You could get hold of it by class name and add the `unselectable` attribute. Since you've tagged this question as jQuery, you could use something like `$("button.someClass").attr("unselectable", "on");`.

Comment: `unselectable` saved my life