# Insert text in Jquery ui selectable Table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, contenteditable

I have two tables inside `contenteditable` div. I applied `selectable` class to first table. My problem is, I can insert text in second table but can not insert text in first table.

https://jsfiddle.net/waou22dp/8/

Comment: But with the same **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waou22dp/4/)** you gave I was able to insert text in first Table too!! What is the problem??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I checked my fiddle and found that `selectable` class is not applied to first table.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/waou22dp/11/

Comment: @ketan. He is trying to **`select the table`** and make it **`editable`** at a single instance and I don't think it's possible!!

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert text in input box in contenteditable div in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863549/insert-text-in-input-box-in-contenteditable-div-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to the version of `jquery` you were referring.

You were referring `jquery-1.8.3.js` and `jquery-ui-1.9.2.js` which might have caused incompatibility with the versions and in the `console` I was able to see `.selectable` function was `undefined` and **`an Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectable is not a function` error**. Now I just changed the `jquery` version to `jquery-2.0.2.js` and jquery-ui-1.10.3.js` and that actually is compatible!!

Check this **[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waou22dp/8/)**

**UPDATE:**

I don't think it's possible!! because you are trying to override an event where both cannot occur at a time!! I tried applying below method, but even that will not be useful many times. Having said that it will be working, I mean click happens and it becomes editable only after multiple consecutive clicks:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tbl1').selectable({
        filter: "td"
    }).on('click',function(){
        $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
    });
});
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waou22dp/12/)**