# get cursor position in contenteditable div with html-tags

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following div and button:

```
<div id="msg" contenteditable></div>
<button class="button">Add some text</button>
```

And I use the following code to get the cursor position:

```
function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
  var caretPos = 0,
    sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
        caretPos = range.endOffset;
      }
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
      var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
      editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
      var tempRange = range.duplicate();
      tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
      tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
      caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
    }
  }
  return caretPos;
}
```

A JSFiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/quqnmp9m/

If you click on the button, this is added:

```
<span class="font-weight:700;">Hello world!</span>
```

If you just enter some text in the div, everything works: the cursor position is calculated correctly. But if you click on the button, the function getCaretPosition fails.

**What do I want?**

I want to REAL cursor position. Not the cursor position from the visible part of the div. An example:

If the content is

```
Hello world!
```

the cursor position should be 12.

But if the content is

```
<span class="font-weight:700;">Hello world!</span>
```

the cursor position should be 50. Not 12. The tag should be included as well.

Does anyone have an idea?

I have checked and tried the following answers:

- [Get a range's start and end offset's relative to its parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022)
- [JavaScript: get cursor position in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620439/javascript-get-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div)
- [Cursor Positioning in ContentEditable Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218043/cursor-positioning-in-contenteditable-div) (someone answers with "saving the position of the cursor") but how exactly can I achieve this? And is this the way to go?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just read again and I think maybe my answer is only partly what you are looking for?

Comment: @Sam did you get any solution for this? The accepted answer doesn't work. If you did get a solution, can you post your working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you what you want. It will give you the length of the html also.

https://jsfiddle.net/ko5Lhbeo/

**Change this:**

```
$('.msg').on('keyup',function(e){
    $('.cursor').html(getCaretPosition(document.getElementById('msg')));
})
```

**to this:**

```
// Added DOMSubtreeModified event here to fire whenever any modifications to the sub tree
$('.msg').on('keyup DOMSubtreeModified',function(e) {
    $('.cursor').html($('#msg').html().length);
})
```