# get caret position in a contenteditbable div that has multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the caret position in a contenteditable div that has multiple html elements and multiple lines.

I found good solution that returns the caret position based on text only - this is not what I'm looking for.

The best solution I found until now is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386720/get-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-div-with-html-tags). the problem is this does not returns the caret position in a multiple line div scenario.

please help.

thanks in advance,