# Undo TAB in textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

There are many questions about how to prevent focusing next element, when pressing `TAB` in textarea tag and just insert a `\t` character. Or any other character. All of them are answered with something like:

1. Capture a TAB keypress
2. Get current caret position and selection info
3. Replace the value so it will contain `\t` or whatever user wants.

All this works fine until you'll press "Undo" or `CTRL+Z` after `TAB`

If you do this, you will experience some side effects depending on the browser you use:

- Firefox will remove `\t` but caret pos will go to the end and all text in textarea are selected
- Chrome will not count this `\t` as user input so `CTRL+Z` will undo pre-last operation, leaving `\t` in place, there is also some caret problems which are hard to predict
- IE is acting same as Chrome

You can watch this here http://jsfiddle.net/c7zc8/1/

The question is how to make it crossbrowser and "undoable"?

Answer (score 3):

For the latest Chrome (33), the following works:

```
var ta = document.getElementById("textareaId");
ta.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.which===9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand("insertText", false, "\t");
    }
}, false);
```

Reference: 
[Javascript textarea undo redo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553430/javascript-textarea-undo-redo)

For IE, however, there is no perfect solution. IE11 has ms-beginUndoUnit and ms-endUndoUnit, but even that does not work perfectly according to Tim Down in
[internet explorer alternative to document.execCommand("insertText",...), for text insertion that can be undone/redone by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124212/internet-explorer-alternative-to-document-execcommandinserttext-for-tex)

Comment: `document.execCommand("insertText")` doesn't work in Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696

Comment: This answer is OUTDATED and not supported. Please delete this crap.

Comment: Works on current Chromium for me - is there a working alternative w/undo support?