# Unable to delete or insert Text in IE11 div contentEditable using execCommand

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

```
document.execCommand("delete");
document.execCommand("insertText", false, insertString);
```

The above two commands work perfectly fine in *Chrome/Firefox* but i'm unable to use it in IE11.

`document.execCommand("delete")` only works in IE if we select a range of text. How do i get it to work like it in Chrome(i.e like using backspace).

And also anyway how I could use `document.execCommand("insertText", false, insertString)` in IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [internet explorer alternative to document.execCommand("insertText",...), for text insertion that can be undone/redone by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124212/internet-explorer-alternative-to-document-execcommandinserttext-for-tex)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, i did visit that link.

there is no info on "document.execCommand("delete")"

Answer (score 3):

for insertText in IE, there is workaround:

```
 let isIE = function() {
    return document.all || (!!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode);
 }

 let text = "Hello"
 if(isIE()) document.execCommand("paste", false, text);
```

Comment: was using `document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);` earlier which was not working in IE. `document.execCommand("paste", false, text);` worked in IE perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that you've found the workround about insertText.

And below is my advice to delete in IE.

You could see from [the official document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) that the definition of Delete is:

**delete:Deletes the current selection.**

Maybe there is small performance difference between IE11 and Google Chrome like the backspace effect.

In my opinion, if you want to make the delete function work like using backspace in IE11, you could create another function to achieve this.

HTML.

```
<div id="testdiv" contenteditable="true">
    Select something here and after click on delete.
</div>
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="backSpace();" />
```

JS.

```
function backSpace() {
        p = document.getElementById("testdiv");
        c = getCaretPosition(p);
        console.log(getCaretPosition(p));
        str = $("#testdiv").html();
        if (c > 0 && c <= str.length) {
            $("#testdiv").focus().html(str.substring(0, c - 1) + str.substring(c, str.length));

            p.focus();
            var textNode = p.firstChild;
            var caret = c - 1;
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(textNode, caret);
            range.setEnd(textNode, caret);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }

    $.fn.setCursorPosition = function (pos) {
        this.each(function (index, elem) {
            if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
                elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
            } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
                var range = elem.createTextRange();
                range.collapse(true);
                range.moveEnd('character', pos);
                range.moveStart('character', pos);
                range.select();
            }
        });
        return this;
    };

    function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
        var caretPos = 0,
            sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
                    caretPos = range.endOffset;
                }
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
                var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
                editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
                var tempRange = range.duplicate();
                tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
                tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
                caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
            }
        }
        return caretPos;
    }
```

Above code from the thread:[Simulate backspace button JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863823/simulate-backspace-button-js)

I've tried the code and you could see the effect from the capture:[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7oVq.gif)

Comment: i did go through this before, it works as long as there is no carriage return. If i press the enter key 2-3 times, this function does not work(carret position is not incremented on new line). Works only if there is continuous typing.