# Why .insertHTML not working in IE11 browser?

Tags: internet-explorer

Why .insertHTML not working in IE11 browser?Is there any other way to insert html content into rich text editor in IE11?

```
richTextEditor.insertHTML(content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since insertHTML is still not supported by IE11 you'll need something like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691294/96100