# Insert element at cursor position

Tags: jquery

I have a contenteditable div:

```
<div class="r_review_content" contenteditable="true" 
      unselectable="false" style="padding:10px; vertical-align:bottom" ></div>
```

then I have different smiley images. Now what I am trying to achieve is that when I click on smiley image it should get added at cursor location in above div. This is what I have achieved so far:

```
  $(".smiley_icon img").click(function(){
        var img_smiley =$(this).clone().css("width","18px");                
        $('.r_review_content').append(img_smiley);          
        return false;   
    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dLodr1b8/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div

Comment: Thanks isherwood for the fiddle and the answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to isherwood for providing me the link to my answer. 
From there I am using the function given by Tim Down.
However I am putting complete answer which could be helpful for any future beginner trying to make emoticons based feedback box.

`$(".smiley_icon img").click(function(){

    var img_smiley =$(this).clone().css("width","18px").wrap("<div />").parent().html();

    $('#r_review_box-100 .r_review_content').focus(); 
    pasteHtmlAtCaret(img_smiley); //adding html at cursorlocation BY - Tim Down
    return false;

});`