# pasting in contenteditable PRE

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable, pre

Pasting HTML copied from the browser (try CMD-A, CMD-C in gmail) into a contenteditable PRE in Firefox (34.0) puts the new elements **after** the PRE, not inside (inspect to verify).

```
<pre contenteditable="true" style="height:200px; width:200px; border:1px solid red"/>
```

See this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w5cs9pzo/1/

I can only reproduce this problem with PREs - DIVs are fine.

Any workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: My hunch is that this is caused by `<br>` elements in the HTML (versus the well-formed `<br/>`), specifically `<br class="Apple-interchange-newline">`. 

I worked around this by canceling the default paste and using `document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, <TEXT>);`

IE workaround found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div/6691294#6691294.

Comment: `<br>` could only cause a problem if you are using XHTML. Are you?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking, see my jsfiddle. Note: I am using Firefox as the copy source (gmail) and paste target (jsfiddle).