# Paste HTML at caret without using insertNode

Tags: javascript, dom, copy-paste

I have the following method to paste some HTML at the caret position, using `range.insertNode(), sourced from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div)

```
function insertAtCursor(html) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);

            // Preserve the selection
            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } // non IE code removed
}
```

This is for a Windows Store app. I've discovered [a bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4227a316-00dd-417a-b0aa-555a646e9add/u81high-cpu-memory-leak-in-windows-81-universal-apps?prof=required) in Universal Apps for Windows 8.1 where a serious typing lag occurs after a paste event using `range.insertNode()`. The issue only occurs in Windows 8.1 Universal Apps running under Windows 10. I can't replicate the issue under Windows 8.1 (although I definitely have experienced it in the past on Win8.1) - but it happens every time on Windows 10 on several machines using this sample app

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE99EF9560A6740E!230777&authkey=!ACBcfSH4H1BE1s8&ithint=file%2czip

Does anyone know another way to paste HTML at the caret without using `range.insertNode()`? Windows Store apps using the IE11 rendering engine, so if it works in IE11 it will work in a Store App / Universal App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh. I feel kind of stupid now. The answer is the *second* answer from the link I posted

```
var doc = document.getElementById("your_iframe").contentWindow.document;

// IE <= 10
if (document.selection){
    var range = doc.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML("<b>Some bold text</b>");

// IE 11 && Firefox, Opera .....
}else if(document.getSelection){
    var range = doc.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var nnode = doc.createElement("b");
    range.surroundContents(nnode);
    nnode.innerHTML = "Some bold text";
};
```

When I replace my `insertNode` code with this `surroundContents` method instead, everything works. Now I just have to fork my preferred rich editor and replace the method