# JQUERY: How to remove all HTML tags except BR and IMG in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I delete all HTML tags except `<img>` and `<br>` in DIV Contenteditable, when I'm writing inside

```
<div id='aa' contenteditable='true'></div>
```

So far i am using

```
$('#aa').text()
```

But it deletes everything

And I try to use this

```
$('#aa').keydown(function(e) {
var datasts=$("#aa").html();
datasts=datasts.substr(datasts.length - 1);
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 'enter');
return false;
}
});
document.getElementById("aa").addEventListener("input", function() {
var a=$("#aa").text();
$("#aa").html(a.replace('enter', '<br/>'));
}, false);
```

But the result is not maximal

---

This is the code I have changed

```
<div id='aa' contenteditable='true'></div>

<button onclick="$('#aa').html('<img src='https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg'>');">
aa
</button>

<script>
$('#aa').keydown(function(e) {
var datasts=$("#aa").html();
datasts=datasts.substr(datasts.length - 1);
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');
return false;
}
});
document.getElementById("aa").addEventListener("input", function() {
$("#aa").children().not("br, img").remove();
}, false);
</script>
```

*I want to remove the html tags in writing position. When there is copying html, html tag will automatically be deleted*

Comment: please share a working snippet using `<>` to demonstrate your effort and problem.

Comment: I have added into the question

Comment: I want to remove the html tags in writing position. When there is copying html, html tag will automatically be deleted

Comment: Question seems awfully similar to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649792/how-to-get-only-html-code-without-startfragment-on-paste-in-contenteditab

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this, that will remove any child of #aa if that child isn't a br or an img

```
$("#aa").children().not("br, img").remove()
```

Comment: It deletes everything, including ordinary characters

Comment: I want to delete when else write in div:contenteditable

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. What are you trying to delete? When do you want to delete items

Comment: I have added the whole code to the question, check it,, As I write directly, it does not work

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of it working (you had *$("#aa").html(* around my code which shouldn't have been there). https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6338/

Comment: so everything gets deleted inside #aa except for <br> and <img> tags

Comment: Cool, but enter does not work yet, document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br/>');

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6345/ updated to add enter press  (pasteHtmlAtCaret code came from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div)

Comment: this is work,, but 1 question again,, im can insert img using button, <button onclick="$('#aa').html('<img src='https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg'> sdsd');">
aa
</button> this is not work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6347/ that'll insert an image at the curser. If this answered your question please mark this question as the correct answer

Comment: The code turns off the copypaste function,, Copypaste does not run on the code. how to fix it? :(