# How to get only html code without <!--StartFragment--> on paste in contenteditable div..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, paste

I used **contenteditable div** to paste and replace all html tags with `<br>` tag. But the pasted html start with `<html><body><!--StartFragment-->` and end with `<!--EndFragment--></body></html>`.

When i try to replace pasted html with `<br>` tag, it inserts three `<br>` tags at start position. So the **pasted content start and end with three line breaks unnecessarily**.

How to **remove those unwanted tags** on paste..?

#### Javascript code used to get pasted html content:

```
$(document).on('paste','#div-id',function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
});
```

**Note**: Used regex to replace all tags with break tag(except `<img>` and `<br>` tag)

```
var replacedData = pastedData.replace(/\<(?!img|br).*?\>/g,"<br>");
```

Comment: Are you taking a class with this person or something?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649194/jquery-how-to-remove-all-html-tags-except-br-and-img-in-div#43649194

Comment: @Brad.. No. I am asking about to replace with <br> tag. Three unwanted break tags gets added in start and end position while replace.. How to solve this..?

Comment: @Brad.. This problem is due to the above mentioned unwanted tags..