# contenteditable IE11 document.execCommand foreColor issue (works properly on Firefox)

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm creating a simple typing tool (I have to use IE11). Note that this does not happen in Firefox, where everything works just fine.

The execCommand forecolor is giving me a undesired result:

I type some text with black, then let's say I want to type inside one of the black words but with a different color. If I place the caret in the word and click the new color I want to use (which executes document.execCommand('foreColor', false, currentForeColor);) the whole word will become of the newly selected color. If I first select the color and then place the caret in the middle of the word, the color will remain black (this also happens on Firefox).

There are a few screenshot to give an idea.

Type some black text:

[image: type some black text]

Click in the middle of the word and select a color:

[image: click in the middle of the word and select a color]

The actual desired result:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is that once you chose a color it will type with that color wherever you place the caret and without affecting the present words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to set the color each time the user types in a character.

```
event.preventDefault();
var tmpHtml = "<font color='" + currentForeColor + "'>" + event.key + "</font>";
pasteHtmlAtCaret(tmpHtml);
console.log(tmpHtml);
```

And the function I use to paste html (found here: [pastHtmlAtCaret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div))

```
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html, selectPastedContent) {
var sel, range;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE9 and non-IE
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
        // only relatively recently standardized and is not supported in
        // some browsers (IE9, for one)
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
        while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
            lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        var firstNode = frag.firstChild;
        range.insertNode(frag);

        // Preserve the selection
        if (lastNode) {
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
            if (selectPastedContent) {
                range.setStartBefore(firstNode);
            } else {
                range.collapse(true);
            }
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
} else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    // IE < 9
    var originalRange = sel.createRange();
    originalRange.collapse(true);
    sel.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    if (selectPastedContent) {
        range = sel.createRange();
        range.setEndPoint("StartToStart", originalRange);
        range.select();
    }
}
}
```

Of course it's not a perfect solution, and after a certain number of elements the typing starts to get laggy.