# click() doesn't work as enter the button by mouse manually

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension so it will automatically do things when I enter a website, everything is working good so far except 1 problem.

There is an text input so I can put in the value and enter another button, it is working well when I do manually by hand and mouse. But when it comes to coding, it is not working as I wanted. The code is as below:

```
  var   content = document.getElementsByClassName("groupButton")[0];
  var kbButtons = content.getElementsByTagName("button");

 // add mouse event for input 
  document.querySelector('input#InputNumber')
  .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}));
  
  document.querySelector('input#InputNumber')
  .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', {bubbles: true}));
    
  document.querySelector('input#InputNumber')
  .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup', {bubbles: true}));
  
  document.querySelector('input#InputNumber')
  .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('orientationchange', {bubbles: true}));
    document.querySelector('input#InputNumber')
  .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {bubbles: true}));

 
  // add keyboard button for input  
  setTimeout(() => {
  const el = document.querySelector('input#InputNumber');
  el.focus();
  for (const type of ['blur','focusin','focusout','keydown', 'keypress', 'keyup'])
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(type, {bubbles: true}));
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '70');
},4000);


  // click on button
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    
    kbButtons[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}));
  }, 5000);
```

the function click() is working well but it doesnt catch value from the input that I set as 50. It is just always 10 as it is from the beginning. I dont know why this is happening?  If somebody can help me can we do a teamviewer session? Since the website needs login credential and I can do this so you can help me soon.

Thanks a lot and look forward to hearing from everybody who has this experience.

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: Hi, I tried this already before but it is still not working. I think it is related to mouse event, because when I just use that to input the field automatically and then click on the button manually, it would be working. I think it would be related to mouse out and then go to click button. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I also think we need to have different way of doing click() function. Do you know how to move mouse from current place to that button and then do the click?

Comment: Use devtools to find which event listeners are attached, see [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64096646). As you can see, dispatchEvent should be used instead of click().

Comment: I tried but it is still not working. Do you have some time to take a look at my site now? Just few minutes if you can help me. I am really thankful if you can take some time on it.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work like that. You need to show [MCVE](/help/mcve) of the new attempt and a screenshot of devtools event listeners panel.

Comment: yes this is the  image of those events.
https://imgur.com/a/lWAO1mj

and I also  just updated the code which were from the orginal question.

Comment: Not all of those events are for keyboard so you should dispatch `new Event`. Also try dispatching some of the events that appear with `[x] ancestors` enabled and `{bubbles: true}` added.

Comment: hi. I just updated the code in orginial post, which I updated some mouse and keyboard events but it is still not working. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: When I tried to print out things in the console tag to see if those events are attached to the input, and I see those are attached but the problem I see is
 all Event are {isTrusted: false}.

 But when I detect with clicking and input manually it would be {isTrusted: true}. 

Do you think this would the factor that caused the issue? I attached the image as this url:  https://imgur.com/eJ9s3Kd

Comment: Sites rarely check isTrusted but try [How to trigger an ‘isTrusted=true’ click event using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53488689)

Comment: If it rarely check isTrust, then do you have any idea why it is still not working. You see the image url in which many events have been attached to input right? I am really in need of solving this. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222507/discussion-between-user3051274-and-woxxom).