# How to fill the web whatsapp text field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am trying to fill the text field in Web WhatsApp using Javascript but it is not working according to my requirement.

I want to write the text in the text field and then click the Send button programmatically using JS.

Is that possible?

I tried following code in console,

```
document.getElementsByClassName('_2_1wd copyable-text selectable-text')[1].innerText = "hello this is test\\n"
```

[image: ScreenShot]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAXAP.png)

It is writing in the text field but overlapping the existing placeholder and send button also doesn't show by trying programmatically.

Comment: What was the error? What happened vs what did you expect to happen?

Comment: It's likely going to be an input field which means `innerText` is the wrong API here. You will likely need `value`

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByClassName('_2_1wd copyable-text selectable-text')[1].value = "hello this is test"` and use the `submit` event on the form to submit.

Comment: Might need to notify the page, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64096646).

Comment: @Dominik, I tried by using 'value' but it doesn't work, because element is 'div' in its nature not an input field.

Comment: @TaurusCodes we won't be able to help you if we don't know the html of that page. Try to create a re-producible, self-contained example of your problem here on SO. Preferably use the code snippet function

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is not advisable,

But you can do it by triggering events..

```
var inputEvent = new InputEvent('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});
var clickEvent = new InputEvent('click', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});

var selectableTextDiv = select that textDiv;
selectableTextDiv.innerText = "You desired Message";
selectableTextDiv.dispatchEvent(inputEvent)
// After triggeing input event.. you will see the send button
var sendButton = //selectThatButton
sendButton .dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

But as I mentioned above "It is not advisable"